# xarray n00b question: can it handle irregularly sized matrices?

Tags: python, tensor, python-xarray

What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
x['a'] = np.array( [1,2,3] ) # 1x3
x['b'] = np.array( [ (1,2,3), (4,5,6) ] ) # 2x3
# a and b differ in the size of their first dimension
```

My first intuition is a dictionary of arrays/pandas Dataframes but maybe xarray can handle this more elegantly.  I did a quick scan of the documentation and examples but didn't see what I was looking for.

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thank you. :)

Comment: Your question does not make clear what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Opps, the functionality I'm looking for is in [xarray.Datasets](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/quick-overview.html#datasets).